# Retrieve the attempted password in the authFail closure

Tags: grails, spring-security

Grails 1.3.7 + spring-security-core plugin

Is there a way to retrieve the password entered in the login form from the authFail closure?  I can get the username via

```
session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]
```

but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the password.

```
session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY]
```

always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

first: Just don't do it. I bet whatever you want to do with it will break security.
Writing the password into the password field in a HTML form is one of those bad cases.
Storing the password in the session is also not a very good idea.

To answer your question: Overwrite the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and use your custom class in the spring configuration.

Copy the content of the attemptAuthentication and add whatever you need to the session.
It would be very wise to remove the password from the session after you did what you need

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_PASSWORD_KEY);
```

Filter class:

```
    public class MyFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_PASSWORD_KEY = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_PASSWORD";


    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        // Place the last username attempted into HttpSession for views
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session != null || getAllowSessionCreation()) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY, TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(username));
            request.getSession().setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_PASSWORD_KEY, TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(password));
        }

        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```